# Optional Parameter is always set to default value

Tags: php, doctrine

I am having a very strange problem with method parameters.

I have this method:

```
public function getOverstock($getQtyOrdering = false) {
        var_dump('here', $getQtyOrdering);
        if ($getQtyOrdering === false) {
            return $this->overstock;
        }

        //sort the collection by the quantity field before returning
        $iterator = $this->overstock->getIterator();
        $iterator->uasort(function ($a, $b) {
            return ($a->getQty() < $b->getQty()) ? 1 : -1;
        });
        $sortResult = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection(iterator_to_array($iterator));
        return $sortResult;

    }
```

Which is called like this:

```
$overstocks = $line->getOption()->getOverstock(true);
```

When the parameter is dumped, it is always false. How is this possible?

Comment: What you're implying isn't possible with just the code provided. Something else is going on.

Comment: possibly you call the function from another place ?

Comment: @JonStirling I'm perfectly prepared to accept that, but nothing I can think of or google gets me anywhere close to these symptoms. If there is other useful information, I have no idea what it is.

Comment: @Izopi4a I've tested for this. The called I provided is the only place it is used in the current request.

Comment: @steelpush because there isn't a symptom, there is nothing strictly wrong with the code you've provided, you just don't know what _is_ happening, and that's not something we (or google) can tell you. Do some debugging.

Comment: maybe answer lays in here $line->getOption()

Comment: @Izopi4a $line->getOption looks and behaves fine when dumped / used for any other purpose in the context. It seems unlikely to involved.

Comment: @JonStirling Right, debug what exactly? I can find nothing wrong except a parameter being inexplicably being ignored. I can find no server settings, no php settings and no code issues even indirectly related. I need leads, thats the purpose of the question.

Comment: Sorry, but again, there is nothing wrong with what you've provided. This isn't a setting thing either. If that method is getting `false` then _somewhere_ you have code calling that method with either `false` (or nothing), or the call is getting intercepted by something along the way, none of which we have enough information / code to tell you one way or another. All we can say, is PHP does not randomly override an arg with a default..

Comment: @JonStirling I solved it thanks to your insistence. I had not considered stacktracing to look at the execution path from within the method. Once I did that it was obvious that old proxies were mangling the call silently. I'll give you an answer tick if you want to repost your last comment as an answer.

Comment: @steelpush \o/ Good work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with what you've provided. This isn't a setting thing either.

If that method is getting false then somewhere you have code calling that method with either false (or nothing), or the call is getting intercepted by something along the way, none of which we have enough information / code to tell you one way or another.

All we can say, is PHP does not randomly override an arg with a default.